# How do I export the result of a query to an Excel file?

Tags: sql, excel, netbeans

Given the following query:

```
     String SQL = "select name,years from person"; 
     ps = con.createStatement();
     rs = ps.executeQuery(SQL);
     jTable1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
```

How can I easily export data to an Excel file?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
    try Apache POI... http://poi.apache.org/ 

Workbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Java Books");
  // create header row
  HSSFRow headerRow = sheet.createRow(0)
Cell nameHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(0);
Cell addressHeaderCell = headerRow.createCell(1);

String sql = "select name, address from student";
PrepareStatement ps =  connection.prepareStatement(sql);
ResultSet resultSet = ps.executeQuery();    

int row = 1;
while(resultSet.next()) {
    String name = resultSet.getString("name");
    String address = resultSet.getString("address");

    Row dataRow = sheet.createRow(row);

    Cell dataCell = dataRow.createCell(0);
    dataCell.setCellValue(name);

    Cell dataAddressCell = dataRow.createCell(1);
    dataAddressCell.setCellValue(address);

    row = row + 1;
}

String outputDirPath = "";//PATH for export location
FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(outputDirPath);
wb.write(fileOut);
fileOut.close();
```